# WP7 Download addition content to app (sound lib)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, ftp, download

Is there any good way to download additional content for my app in wp7? Now my best idea is FTP.

Comment: What kind of content are you looking to download? What size is the content you want to download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just host the files on a web server and then download it on a background thread and write the files to isolated storage. That is going to be easier than FTP as I don't know if there are any free FTP libraries for Windows Phone right now.

Here is an [example of downloading files and saving them to isolated storage](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/08/16/download-and-store-media-for-playback-in-windows-phone-7-using-mediastreamsource.aspx). It does a bit more than you might need but it should be a good jumping off point. Also don't use the performance progress bar mentioned in that article but rather the [Progress Indicator](http://debugmode.net/2011/09/30/system-tray-progressindicator-in-windows-phone-7-5-or-mango-phone/).

If the files are highly compressible I would also consider zipping them and then unzipping them on the phone using something like [Silverlight SharpZipLib](http://slsharpziplib.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Only use the Silverlight SharpZipLib if you are able to comply with the conditions of the GPL licence

Comment: He's probably ok.  It uses the library exception.  From the sharpziplib site:  "Bottom line In plain English this means you can use this library in commercial closed-source applications."